# How do I move an element diagonally and after another animation in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have an HTML/CSS element:

```
<div id="box">
        <p> BOX </p>
    </div>

#box {
      width: 100px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: skyblue;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0px;
      top: 200px;
      text-align: center;
      font-family: Times New Roman;
}
```

I need it to move from its position in the middle of the page diagonally down and to the left (to the left corner). I've tried this:

```
$(function() {
            $("button").click(function() {
                $("#box").animate({
                    left: $(window).width() - 200
                    bottom: $(window).width() - 200
                }
        });
    });
```

How do I do this with jQuery and have it done after it's been on the page a few seconds (for a different animation to occur first)?

Comment: Better to use `top` instead of `bottom`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following.

```js
$(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("#box").animate({
      left: $(window).width() - 100,
      top: $(window).height() - 200
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: skyblue;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Times New Roman;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <p>BOX</p>
</div>
<button>Go</button>
```

You were using `width` property for both. You must use `width` and `height`. Also it's better to use `top` versus `bottom` in this case. You can use `bottom`, yet I would suggest something like:

```
bottom: $("#box").height()
```

In this way, the property of the `top` will be N Pixels from the "Bottom".

See More: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_bottom.asp